# Type CustomDomComponent is not assignable to type 'FC<MotionBoxProps>'. Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am getting Type CustomDomComponent is not assignable to type 'FC'.   Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible when upgrading to latest Chakra (2.5.5 at the time of writing).

**src/components/motion/Box.tsx**

```
import { Box, HTMLChakraProps } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { HTMLMotionProps, motion } from "framer-motion";
import React from "react";

type Merge<P, T> = Omit<P, keyof T> & T;
type MotionBoxProps = Merge<HTMLChakraProps<"div">, HTMLMotionProps<"div">>;

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const MotionBox: React.FC<MotionBoxProps> = motion(Box);
```